# How to make more room for subplot text fields in Python's matplotlib?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, figure

How to make more room for subplot text fields in Python's matplotlib? Now it looks too messy: some of the text fields are going over each other. [image]

Here is a part of the current code for the figure:

```
    fig_a = fig.add_subplot(2,2,i)
    fig_a.set_title(r'$T_{0} = %.3g N/m, V_{0} = %.6g$ m/s' % (counter, V0))
    fig_a.plot(xx,f)
    plt.xlim(-kappa,kappa)
    plt.xlabel(r'$\eta$')
    plt.ylim(-0.1,1.1)
    if ((i == 1) or (i == 3)):
        plt.ylabel(r'$f(\eta)$')
    i = i + 1
```

How to change it to not to look so messy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=None, hspace=None)
```

You're going to want to modify hspace, the vertical space between subplots: I found hspace=0.4 looked okay with your code, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

you might also try out

```
   pylab.tight_layout()
```

works usually fine for me and also eeks out some more space at the corners for the graphs themseves.